# Connecting a Heroku app to MongoDB atlas using Fixie (for static IP addresses) result in request timeout

Tags: node.js, heroku, proxy, mongodb-atlas

I have a nodeJS application deployed on Heroku that connects to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. The connection works fine when I whitelist all IP addresses `0.0.0.0/0`

However, I want to restrict requests to those coming from my Heroku app. To do that, I have installed the [Fixie](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie) addon. It *"provides Heroku applications with a fixed set of static IP addresses for outbound requests"*.

The static IP addresses (two IP addresses) can be found at [Fixie's Dashboard](https://dashboard.usefixie.com/#/account). You should then add them to the IP Access list in MongoDB Atlas Dashboard.

However, when I do that the Heroku app stops working (request timeout). I checked **Fixie's Logs** which did not show any requests. This suggests that there is something wrong with the Heroku-Fixie connection.

To double-check I tried setting up a Fixie proxy locally to check if the requests will be added to the log, which it did. This makes me suspect an issue with the Heroku-Fixie connection as I previously mentioned.

For reference, this [Tutorial](https://www.berato.tech/connecting-your-heroku-app-to-atlas) described how to setup Fixie in Heroku to be used with Atlas. I have actually followed the same steps mentioned by the author but I could not get it to work.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing with a different add-on (quotaguard) and I ran into the same issue. It seems there an issue with the attachment between the Heroku app and the proxy add-on

Comment: did you ever get this working? got the same problem here

Comment: @benmneb I could not get to work unfortuantely. This was a personal project and I had to stop it for a while. However, as far as I remember it seems that just setting up the add-on was not enough. And I thought that I might have to see how to force all request sent from Node.JS to go through the proxy (using the ip it provides). So maybe start from here